# Creating a ggplot() from scratch in R to illustrate results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a bit new to R and this is the first time I'd like to use ggplot(). My aim is to create a few plots that will look like the template below, which is an output from the package `effects` for those who know it:

[image: the template below]:

Given this data:

```
     Average     Error     Area
1: 0.4407528 0.1853854 Loliondo
2: 0.2895050 0.1945540 Seronera
```

How can I replicate the plot seen in the image with labels, error bars as in `Error` and the line connecting both `Average` points?

I hope somebody can put me on the right track and then I will go from there for other data I have.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggplot2::geom_errorbar` you can add error bars by first deriving your `ymin` and `ymax`.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~Average, ~Error, ~Area,
0.4407528, 0.1853854, "Loliondo",
0.2895050, 0.1945540, "Seronera")

dfnew <- df %>% 
  mutate(ymin = Average - Error,
         ymax = Average + Error)

p <-   ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Area, y = Average)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") + geom_line(aes(group = 1), colour = "blue") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Area, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), colour = "purple")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering how can I edit the colours so that they similarly match the plot I posted?

Comment: I have edited the post to add the colours. there are a number of ways to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty one that is similar to what was just posted:

```
df <- 
  tibble(
    average = c(0.44, 0.29),
    error = c(0.185, 0.195),
    area = c("Loliondo", "Seronera")
  )

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = area)) +
  geom_line(
    aes(y = average, group = 1),
    color = "blue"
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = average - 0.5 * error, ymax = average + 0.5 * error),
    color = "purple",
    width = 0.1
  )
```

The trickiest part here is the `group = 1` segment, which you need for the line to be drawn with factors on the x axis.

The aes(x = area) goes up top because it's used in both geoms, while the y, group, ymin, and ymax are used only locally. The color and width arguments appear outside of the aes() call since they are used for appearance modifications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm getting the following error when using your script:```Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `x` is function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace```

Comment: I'm not sure - after loading `library(tidyverse)`, the above code works for me in a fresh R session.